# Where is the custom .bundle file I added to my project/app in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I added a new Target in my app and selected *Bundle*. I named it *myBundle* I copied some resource files to the bundle. I cleared the build and again rebuild the app. The *.app* file is available in the *Products* folder. But I don't see the *myBundle.bundle* file there..

Did anybody see it?

:)

Comment: I didn't see it, but I will keep an eye out for it and it if comes this way i'll tell it you were looking for it. :)

Comment: @Simon Lee: Thanks man.. I need to find it soon.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the bundle is assigned to your target. You can Get Info on the budle and check the target is checked (for the relevant target), if it isn't then it won't be included in the build.

Comment: Wow. It came to me. There it is. I can see it now. Thanks for telling it that I was looking for it and sending it back to me.

Comment: They are slippery little things so don't beat yourself up about it! :)